# CStdioFile problems with encoding on read file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, file-io, mfc

I can't read a file correctly using CStdioFile.

I open notepad.exe, I type `àèìòùáéíóú` and I save twice, once I set codification as `ANSI` (really is `CP-1252`) and other as `UTF-8`.

Then I try to read it from MFC with the following block of code

```
BOOL ReadAllFileContent(const CString &FilePath, CString *fileContent)
{
    CString sLine;
    BOOL isSuccess = false;

    CStdioFile input;
    isSuccess = input.Open(FilePath, CFile::modeRead);
    if (isSuccess) {
        while (input.ReadString(sLine)) {
            fileContent->Append(sLine);
        }
        input.Close();
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

When I call it, with ANSI file I've got the expected result `àèìòùáéíóú` 
but when I try to read the UTF8 encoded file I've got `Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº`

I would like my function works with all files regardless of the encoding.

Why I need to implement?

**.EDIT.**

- Unfortunately, in the real app, files come from external app so change the file encoding isn't an option.I must be able to read both UTF-8 and CP-1252 files.
- Any file is valid `ANSI`, what notepad told `ANSI` is really `Windows-1252` encode.
- I've figured out a way to read `UTF-8` and `CP-1252` right based on the example provided [here](https://vcpptips.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-read-unicode-text-files/). Although it works, I need to pass the file encode which I don't know in advance.

Thnks!

Comment: Years ago, I recall the MFC `CStdioFile` was limited and didn't work well with Unicode. I found a better replacement on CodeProject: [`CStdioFileEx`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4119/CStdioFile-derived-class-for-multibyte-and-Unicode). You may want to take a look at it; it worked well in several projects. I don't know if more modern versions of MFC improved `CStdioFile`.

Comment: _"I would like my function works with all files regardless of the encoding."_ -- such a function is simply not possible because of the limitations of the plain text file format, which doesn't provide a standard way of defining the encoding. If you are lucky, the file begins with a Unicode BOM, but for ANSI files you are out of luck. You either assume the "current code page for non-Unicode programs" defined by the OS or you have the user explicitly enter a code page.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use the class as advertised here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7958/CTextFileDocument

It has excellent support for reading and writing text files of various encodings including unicode in its various flavours.

I have not had a problem with it.

Comment: I'm sure that its probably the best way to deal with unicode files, but I would like avoid using external libraries as much as possible

Comment: It is a single source and header file. Not a library. Review the source and learn how they do it. Otherwise you are basically reinventing the wheel.  

Comment: I've been testing the library for some days, but unfortunately CTextFileDocument isn't enough good as auto detecting the encodes. If file doesn't have BOM it will detect always as ASCII.

In spite of the poor autodetection (see `ReadDOM()`), In my opinion is a good wrapper class which simplifies a lot the work with encodes, but it doesn't solve my problem.